# knockout.js redirect in view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have the following code on cshtml page.

```
 <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" id="export" class="export-inventory-button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ExportInventory", "Inventory")'">EXPORT INVENTORY</button>
</div>
```

How do I make this work in my view model?

I think I almost got it, but need some help

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" id="export" class="export-inventory-button" data-bind="click: exportInventory">EXPORT INVENTORY</button>
</div>
```

My viewmodel has this code:

```
 function exportInventory() {
                filtererGridData = vm.details;

                var json = ko.mapping.toJSON(vm.details);

                $.ajax({ url: '/Inventory/ExportInventory', type: 'POST' }).done(function (data) {
                    $('#export').html(data);
                }).fail(function (data) {
                    toastr.warn('Could not export data, please contact LGL.');
                });
            }
```

I tried this, but I get errors:

```
function exportInventory() {
                filtererGridData = vm.details;

                var json = ko.mapping.toJSON(vm.details);

                $.ajax({ url: 'location.href="@Url.Action("ExportInventory", "Inventory")"', type: 'POST' }).done(function (data) {
                    window.location.href = responseText.url;
                    $('#export').html(data);
                }).fail(function (data) {
                    toastr.warn('Could not export data, please contact LGL.');
                });
            }
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: and what errors do you get?

Comment: The first one just dumps the data to the screen. The second one returns a 404 error. Url not found ="@Url.Action("ExportInventory", "Inventory"). I don't think it parses the line correctly.

Comment: And is your javascript inside your cshtml page?

Comment: The function exportInventory is in the viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're trying to pass in the url to the ajax call is probably not working the way you expect.  Also, you wouldn't need the `location.href=` to be part of the url parameter in the `$.ajax()` call.

If your view model is coded in a script tag right in your cshtml page, you can try this:

```
<!-- cshtml razor view code for generating the html is above this line -->

<script>
    var viewModel = {
        function exportInventory() {
            filtererGridData = vm.details;

            var json = ko.mapping.toJSON(vm.details);

            //allow razor to build a javascript string for you when it renders the html
            //when the browser parses this script, it will just see a simple string
            var myURL = '@Url.Action("ExportINventory", "Inventory")';

            //pass your variable to the jQuery ajax call
            $.ajax({ url: myURL, type: 'POST' }).done(function (data) {
                window.location.href = responseText.url;
                //this line of code would never be called because the browser has navigated away from this page...
                $('#export').html(data);
            }).fail(function (data) {
                toastr.warn('Could not export data, please contact LGL.');
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Load the page and view source.  If the `var myUrl =` line is the correct URL to your controller as a string, then you know that razor kicked in and prepared that for you on render.